# What's the difference between WSDL,DISCO and EVENT?

Tags: web-services

All of them are web services, but what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

WSDL (Web Service Description Language) is a standard notatation for describing a Web Service in xml.

DISCO is a tool for querying SOAP and similar services and extracting useful information from the WSDL provied.

EVENTs is a proposed standard which uses WSDL and extends WSDL to support publish subcribe type event driven processes.

Comment: You mean DISCO doesn't work independently ,need to work with WSDL?

Comment: WSDL is just an XML format! It doesnt do anything itself and is just a way of exchanging information about the available services and the formast for the requests reply messages. You need something else like .NET or AXIS to actually implement these services.

Answer (score 1):

**WSDL**:

**WSDL** is a markup language that describes the web service. In order to use this Web service, the Client application developers need to know the methods exposed by the Web service and the parameters to be passed to these methods. It is imperative that access to these methodologies is available at development time and it is just this need that WSDL addresses.

**DISCO**:

The Web Service Discovery Tool (**DISCO**) is used to discover the URLs of XML Web Services located on a Web server and saves documents related to each XML service on a local disk. The DISCO takes the URL and discovers and produce publishes discovery documents (.wsdl, .xsd, .disco and .dicomap files) as arguments. Some of the options available for use with this tool are:

/d[omain]:domain - Specifies the domain name to use when connecting to a proxy server that requires authentication

/nosave - Does not save the discovered document or results

/nologo - Suppresses the Microsoft startup banner display

/o[ut]:directoryName - Specifies the output directory in which to save the discovered documents. Current directory is the default one.

/p[assword]:password - Specifies the password to use when connecting to a proxy server

/proxy:url - Specifies the URL of the proxy server to use for HTTP requests.

DISCO is a tool, not a web service itself.

**EVENT**:

if you mean to WS-Eventing, see [here](http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-Eventing/).

Comment: Can you **summarize** the differences?

Answer (score 0):

UDDI- UDDI is a central directory. It will have web services listed from multiple domain and servers.

DISCO-  Disco contain web services listed from one domain and server.By which particular web service can be selected.

WSDL- It describe the rules or grammar for the function that are exposed in the web services.